# How can i inherit from all types in mpl::vector?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, multiple-inheritance

I use `mpl::vector` from **boost 1.58**. I have types:

```
typedef mpl::vector <base1, base2, base3> types;
```

If I have a class *derived*, how can i inherit it from all of these types in this `mpl::vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [inherit_linearly](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/inherit-linearly.html).

Example of usage:

```
class A 
{
public:
   void a() {}
};
class B 
{
public:
   void b() {}
};
class C 
{
public:
   void c() {}
};

typedef boost::mpl::vector<A, B, C> types;


class Derived :
public boost::mpl::inherit_linearly<types, 
boost::mpl::inherit<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2> >::type
{
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.a();
   d.b();
   d.c();
}
```